# How to test @app.on_event("shutdown") in FastAPI?

Tags: python, unit-testing, fastapi

I have a simple FastAPI setup as below,

```
# main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.on_event("shutdown")
def app_shutdown():
    with open("shutdown-test-file.txt", "w") as fp:
        fp.write("FastAPI app has been terminated")


@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

How can I write (unit)test for this ***`app_shutdown(...)`*** functionality?

---

#### Related Posts

- [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68018314/how-do-you-trigger-app-on-eventshutdown-for-fastapi-with-uvicorn) is also asking *similar* question, but, not in a *"testing context"*
- The [official doc](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-events/) has something similar, but, there is no example for ***`on_event("shutdown")`***

Comment: Shouldn't the `on_event("shutdown")` be triggered just as the `on_event("startup")` in the example given in the doc?

Comment: Unfortunately, No.

Comment: Might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051581/how-to-trigger-lifespan-startup-and-shutdown-while-testing-fastapi-app/65061155#65061155

Comment: I just tested the official doc example and it works just fine with both `shutdown` and `startup`: `def test_foo():
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        response = client.get('/')` triggers both the `@app.on_event("shutdown")` and the `@app.on_event("startup")` events.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. Could you add a minimal test (for my situation) as an answer below? @MatsLindh

Comment: So is your problem that _the event isn't triggered_, or is the problem with testing the file write functionality?

Comment: The `shutdown` event is getting called properly if I terminate the FastAPI server (not test client). But, I don't any such operations during my test run.

Comment: Same here, I got it working after wrapping with `with` (context manager)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-events/), you need to wrap it in the context manager (a `with` statement) to trigger the events, something like this:

```py
def test_read_items():
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        response = client.get("/items/foo")
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

If you use [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/), you can set up a fixture for it like this:

```py
from main import app
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    with TestClient(app) as c:
        yield c


def test_read_main(client):
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```